# scss function not getting called and stays the same as written in scss after compiling to css

Tags: css, sass

i have a Style.scss file which i compile to css manually then use it in a html file

```
@function BlendColor($color1, $color2, $ratio) {
    $r: min(1, max(0, $ratio));
    $ir: 1 - $r;
    $red: round(red($color1) * $r + red($color2) * $ir);
    $green: round(green($color1) * $r + green($color2) * $ir);
    $blue: round(blue($color1) * $r + blue($color2) * $ir);
    @return rgb($red, $green, $blue);
}

$Mustard : #FFD449;

.Neum-Mustard {
    --Neum-Color: $Mustard;
    --Neum-Light-Shadow: BlendColor($Mustard,#ffffff,0.2);
    --Neum-Dark-Shadow: BlendColor($Mustard,#000000,0.2);
    --Neum-Text: #000000;
}
```

this is all the .scss file has but when i compile it using `node-sass static/scss/Style.scss static/css/Style.css` the new css file keeps getting wrong code

```
.Neum-Mustard {
  --Neum-Color: $Mustard;
  --Neum-Light-Shadow: BlendColor($Mustard,#ffffff,0.2);
  --Neum-Dark-Shadow: BlendColor($Mustard,#000000,0.2);
  --Neum-Text: #000000; }
```

the function line stays the same instead of getting calculated and returning a color.

i want the css file to have correctly compiled scss content.

Comment: `--Neum-Light-Shadow: #{BlendColor($Mustard,#ffffff,0.2)};`

Answer (score 0):

If you use variables like this you have to put them in `#{$var}`:

```
.Neum-Mustard {
  --Neum-Color: #{$Mustard};
  --Neum-Light-Shadow: BlendColor(#{$Mustard},#ffffff,0.2);
  --Neum-Dark-Shadow: BlendColor(#{$Mustard},#000000,0.2);
  --Neum-Text: #000000; 
}
```

Comment: this solved a problem I didn't realized I had but the main problem still persists.